# What are "good" examples of spin manifolds?

Tags: spin-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, big-list, examples

I'm trying to get a grasp on what it means for a manifold to be spin. My question is, roughly:

> What are some "good" (in the sense of illustrating the concept) examples of manifolds which are spin (or not spin) (and why)?

---

For comparison, I'd consider the cylinder and the mobius strip to be "good" examples of orientable (or not) bundles.

---

I've read the answers to [Classical geometric interpretation of spinors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66681/classical-geometric-interpretation-of-spinors) which are helpful, but I'd like specific examples (non-examples) to think about.

Comment: The manifold $X$ is spin iff the loop space $LX$ is orientable. But I don't think this will help. If you look at $spin^c$, almost complexe manifold $M$ is $spin^c$. All of the 4 dimention manifold is $spin^c$. So if more over, $det^(1/2) TM$ exist, $M$ is spin. 

Comment: Projective spaces are good examples and non-examples.  Similarly, you can consider discrete quotients of spheres.  Then depending on the group you quotient by, the resulting space is (or not) spin.

Comment: @shu, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Otis: See a preprint by Stephan Stolz and Peter Teichner (http://web.me.com/teichner/Math/Surveys_files/MPI.pdf), where they prove that M is spin if and only if LM is fusion-orientable and M is string if and only if LM is fusion-spin.

Comment: @Otis:For the spin^c and spin , the reference is the lovely book write by Morgan. http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5866.html.

Comment: @shu, Otis: The fusion condition mentioned by Dmitri Pavlov is essential - a real Enriques surface is not spin, but its loop space is orientable.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's the traditional obstruction-theoretic perspective.  Orientability means the tangent bundle trivializes over a 1-skeleton.  Dually you could think of that as saying the complement of a co-dimension $2$ subcomplex has a trivial tangent bundle.

So admitting a spin structure is the same, but it will be the tangent bundle trivializes over a 2-skeleton, dually the complement of a co-dimension three subcomplex admits a trivial tangent bundle.

A surface is orientable if and only if it contains no Moebius bands -- a regular neighbourhood of any simple closed curve must be a cylinder.  In higher dimensions this translates into a manifold being orientable if and only if it contains no twisted bundles $D^{n-1} \rtimes S^1$, i.e. regular neighbourhoods of simple closed curves are diffeomorphic to $D^{n-1} \times S^1$.

For spin structures there's something very similar.  Of course, a surface admits a spin structure if and only if it is orientable.  It's a more interesting notion in higher dimensions.  The statement there is the manifold is orientable, and if you take a regular neighbourhood of any surface in the manifold, then it has a trivial tangent bundle.   So manifolds like $\mathbb RP^3$ are perfectly valid spin manifolds -- $\mathbb RP^3$ contains $\mathbb RP^2$ but the total space of its normal bundle has a perfectly trivializable tangent bundle.  Technically, the condition is a little stronger than that -- you can trivialize the tangent bundle of the complement of a co-dimension $3$ subset.    So not only can you trivialize the total spaces of normal bundles of surfaces, but even the regular neighbourhoods of unions of surfaces.

So if you want a manifold that isn't spin, the archetype would be a vector bundle over a surface so that the total space does not have a trivializable tangent bundle. Take the $D^2$-bundle over $S^2$ with Euler Class $\chi$.   I think this happens if and only if $\chi$ is even.  I suppose you have more entertaining examples when dealing with the regular neighbourhood of a 2-complex that isn't itself a manifold.

edit: Milnor's "Spin structures on manifolds" in L'Enseignement Mathematique Vol 9 (1963) is an excellent reference for most of the above.  I don't believe he goes into all the descriptions above since I think he wants to keep the article simple.  The Poincare duality interpretation above is a very standard mode of thinking that's employed throughout much of low-dimensional topology.  Kirby's book on 4-manifolds is a nice place to look for this material. Specifically, R. Kirby "The topology of 4-manifolds" Springer-Verlag (1989).   A more modern reference would be Gompf and Stipsicz, but again I don't think they use all the above descriptions.  Milnor and Stasheff's "Characteristic Classes" describes most of the basic constructions involved above, in the obstruction theory section.  In a couple of months I'll be putting up a paper on the arXiv that gives some very combinatorial ways of describing spin and spin^c-structures on manifolds (mostly for computer implementation).  I hope that will be a good reference, too!   But the paper is still unreadable.

Comment: Thanks! This is enlightening. Can you suggest a reference for this?

Answer (score 19):

A simply connected $4$-manifold is spin iff all embedded oriented surfaces have even self-intersection number or, equivalently, if the quadratic form $H_2 (M;Z) \to Z$ induced by the intersection form takes even values.
This is by the following string of arguments:

1. $M$ is spin iff $w_2 (TM)=0$.
2. $w_2 (TM)=0$ iff the linear form $H_2 (M; Z/2) \to Z/2$, $a \mapsto \langle w_2 (TM);a\rangle$ is null.
3. Any class $a \in H_2 (M;Z)$ can be represented as the fundamental class of an embedded oriented surface $F \subset M$.
4. $w_2 (TM)|_F = w_2 (\nu_F)$ by the product formula for Stiefel-Whitney classes and because $F$ is spin.
5. $w_2 (\nu_F)$ is the mod $2$ reduction of the Euler class of the normal bundle of $F$.
6. $\langle [F]; \chi(\nu_F) \rangle $ is the self-intersection number of $F$, or equivalently, the value of the quadratic form at $[F]$.

Now you should play a bit with $4$-manifolds and might get a feeling for the spin condition.

Answer (score 14):

If you know about Steenrod operations, here's a very convenient characterization:

> A manifold $M$ is *Spin* iff its Poincare duality in $H^*(M,\mathbb Z/2)$ is 
>   compatible with $Sq^1$ and $Sq^2$.

Similarly, *oriented* manifolds are those whose Poincare duality in $H^*(M,\mathbb Z/2)$ is compatible with $Sq^1$.

The story continues: *String* manifolds have a Poincare duality in $H^*(M,\mathbb Z/2)$ that is compatible with $Sq^1$, $Sq^2$ and $Sq^4$ (but now, that's no longer an if and only if). My paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2131 with Chris Douglas and Mike Hill describes all that in detail and provides many concrete examples.

Answer (score 8):

If $M$ is a spin manifold, then any submanifold of codimension 1 is also a spin manifold. This yields a lot of examples, for example, that $S^n$ is spin etc.

(I may not have understood your point completely.)

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, one has to demand as well that the submanifold is orientable.

Comment: this is false: see Ryan Budney's answer (RP^2 in RP^3). Maybe this is true if the submanifold is codimension 1 and 2-sided?

Comment: It's true so long as the normal bundle to the codimension 1 submanifold is trivial. So if both manifolds involved are orientable then it's true.