# What are "good" examples of string manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, big-list, examples

Based on [this mathoverlow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80081/what-are-good-examples-of-spin-manifolds), I would like to have a similar list for the case of string manifolds. An $n$-dim. Riemannian manifold $M$ is said to be *string*, if the classifying map of its bundle of orthonormal frames $M \to BO(n)$ lifts to a map $M \to BO(n)<8> = BString(n)$, which is the case if and only if the class $\frac{p_1}{2} \in H^4(M, \mathbb{Z})$ vanishes. There are a lot of models that yield geometric realizations of $String(n)$ either as a topological group (see [Stolz-Teichner](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Stolz%20AND%20Teichner&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=2079378)), infinite-dimensional Lie group (see [Nikolaus-Sachse-Wockel](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4288)) or a  2-group (see [Schommer-Pries](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2483)).

> What are enlightening examples of
>   string manifolds? What are
>   non-examples? When do you have a
>   geometric interpretation of the
>   obstruction class?

So far, I am aware of the list given at the end of [Douglas-Henriques-Hill](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2131). What else is out there?

Comment: There is *always* a geometric interpretation of the obstruction class, namely as the Chern-Simons 2-gerbe associated to the frame bundle of M and the basic gerbe over Spin.

Comment: Here are the string manifolds from the cited paper by Douglas, Henriques, and Hill: RP^{16n+7}, G_2/T, F_4/Spin(9), F_4/G_2.

Answer (score 11):

Qingtao Chen and Fei Han have constructed [[arxiv:0612055](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0612/0612055v2.pdf)] tons of examples of string manifolds and non-string manifolds as complete intersections in products of complex projective spaces.

For integers $s$ and $n_q$ with $1\leq q \leq s$ consider the product
$$
Z:=\mathbb{C}P^{n_1} \times ... \times \mathbb{C}P^{n_s}
$$
and the projection $pr_q:Z \to \mathbb{C}P^{n_q}$ to the $q$th factor. 
For further integers $t$ and $d_{pq}$ with $1 \leq p \leq t$ and $1 \leq q \leq s$, consider for $1 \leq p \leq t$ the line bundle
$$
E_p := \bigotimes_{q=1}^s \;\; pr_q^{*}\mathcal{O}^{d_{pq}}_{q}
$$
over $Z$, where $\mathcal{O}_q$ is the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^{n_q}$.
Now let $V_{d_{pq}}$ be the intersection of the zero loci of smooth global sections  of $E_1,...,E_t$.

$V_{d_{pq}}$ is always a smooth manifold, and the statement of Proposition 3.1 of the above paper is:

> **Theorem**. Let $m_q$ be the number of non-zero elements in the $q$th column of the matrix $D := (d_{pq})$. Suppose that $m_q +2 \leq n_q$. Then, $V_{d_{pq}}$ is string if and only if 
>   $$
> D^t D = diag(n_1 + 1,...,n_s+1).
> $$